# Recursive name resolution - Message exchange

Tags: dns, recursive-query

I was reading about recursive name resolution, and I understand how it works and all. But, I wanted to know that if a client queried a url like this:

```
http://www.dept.abc.edu/~dept103/
```

then how are the messages exchanged? Like will the first contacted DNS server query with an iterative query to the edu DNS server first to obtain a referral to abc.edu and so on?

What about the `~dept103`? Is that used too?

Answer (score 0):

`~dept103` has nothing to do with DNS. In this instance it's a folder name, but it could be a file, or query string.

If the query can not be resolved locally, for example from cache, then an outside name server is contacted.

First the root DNS server is queried, then `.edu`, then `abc.edu`, then `dept.abc.edu` and finally `www.dept.abc.edu`.

More info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc775637%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, here ~dept103 is not a folder but a particular page on a website. Still that won't be needed in the DNS?